# how is go block implemented in clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

I learned that on JVM go blocks are executed in a pool of 8 threads by default, but what "tricks" core.async is using to get the appearance of multithreaded behavior in JavaScript (or JVM Clojure without 'real' threads)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What transformation is go macro doing to the user’s code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244700/what-transformation-is-go-macro-doing-to-the-user-s-code)

Comment: @bfabry no, this is a different question, I asked what "tricks" are used to make it work in clojurescript, there the question is what transformations go macro is doing to code

Comment: The "tricks" that it is doing is it's rewriting the code inside the `go` block via the `go` macro. So I guess they may not be the same question but they have the same answer.