# What transformation is go macro doing to the user’s code?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

How go macro transforms the code

```
(let [c1 (chan)
      c2 (chan)]
  (go (while true
        (let [[v ch] (alts! [c1 c2])]
          (println "Read" v "from" ch))))
  (go (>! c1 "hi"))
  (go (>! c2 "there")))
```

Comment: Have you tried/looked at what `macroexpand` etc. shows?

Comment: Please see the Clojure email list:  clojure@googlegroups.com

Comment: @cfrick yes, but it is difficult to comprehend, I am new to clojure and not yet comfortable reading code

Comment: @AlanThompson thanks, will try that

Comment: yes, the macro is not trivial - the author of that macro claimed it took them a year to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a state machine at the back.  You can read more in [The State Machines of core.async](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/08/02/the-state-machines-of-core-async/)

Comment: great thank you! Also found this series from Tim Baldridge  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3PZMIwXN_g